# Numpy.polyfit Not Returning Polynomial

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to create a python program in which the user inputs a set of data and the program spits out an output in which it creates a graph with a line/polynomial which best fits the data.

This is the code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = []
y = []
x_num = 0
while True:
  sequence = int(input("Input 1 number in the sequence, type 9040321 to stop"))
  if sequence == 9040321:
    
    poly = np.polyfit(x, y, deg=2, rcond=None, full=False, w=None, cov=False)
    plt.plot(poly)
    plt.scatter(x, y, c="blue", label="data")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
    break
  else:
    y.append(sequence)
    x.append(x_num)
    x_num += 1
```

I used the polynomial where I inputed `1, 2, 4, 8` each in separate inputs. MatPlotLib graphed it properly, however, for the degree of 2, the output was the following image:
[image: Output]

This is clearly not correct, however I am unsure what the problem is. I think it has something to do with the degree, however when I change the degree to 3, it still does not fit. I am looking for a graph like y=sqrt(x) to go over each of the points and when that is not possible, create the line that fits the best.

Edit: I added a `print(poly)` feature and for the selected input above, it gives `[0.75 0.05 1.05]`. I do not know what to make of this.

Comment: `polyfit` returns the poly coefficients.  `[0,1,0]` means `y = 0*x**2 + 1*x + 0`.  Which is what I expect from `x==y`.  What were you expecting?

Comment: I was expecting polyfit to return something to the effect of x**1/2 for this particular one. However, for the degree of 1, I used `1,3,5,7` however it gave me a wonky response. I was expecting a straight line connecting all of the points using the line of `y=x+1`

Comment: Ok yeah, I switched x and y however the polyfit did not improve. I also changed the x-values to start at 0.

Comment: Do you know what we mean by the coefficients of a polynomial?

Comment: Yes, for example in the polynomial `2x^2 -3x + 2` the coefficients are `2, -3, 2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Approximation by a second degree polynomial

[`np.polyfit`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) gives the coefficients of a polynomial close to the given points.  To plot the polynomial as a smooth curve with matplotlib, you need to calculate a lot of `x,y` pairs.  Using `np.linspace(start, stop, numsteps)` for the `x`s, numpy's vectorization allows calculating all the corresponding `y`s in one go. E.g. `ys = a * x**2 + b * x + c`.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
y = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]
plt.scatter(x, y, color='crimson', label='given points')

poly = np.polyfit(x, y, deg=2, rcond=None, full=False, w=None, cov=False)
xs = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 100)
ys = poly[0] * xs ** 2 + poly[1] * xs + poly[2]
plt.plot(xs, ys, color='dodgerblue', label=f'$({poly[0]:.2f})x^2+({poly[1]:.2f})x + ({poly[2]:.2f})$')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: plotting result of np.polyfit]

## Higher degree approximating polynomials

Given `N` points, an `N-1` degree polynomial can pass exactly through each of them.  Here is an example with 7 points and polynomials of up to degree 6,

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
y = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]
plt.scatter(x, y, color='black', zorder=3, label='given points')

for degree in range(0, len(x)):
    poly = np.polyfit(x, y, deg=degree, rcond=None, full=False, w=None, cov=False)
    xs = np.linspace(min(x) - 0.5, max(x) + 0.5, 100)
    ys = sum(poly_i * xs**i for i, poly_i in enumerate(poly[::-1]))
    plt.plot(xs, ys, label=f'degree {degree}')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: Higher degree polynomials]

## Another example

```py
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [1, 1, 6, 5, 5]
```

[image: [1, 1, 6, 5, 5]]

Comment: This works for `1,2,4,8` but when I go and input `1,2,4,8,16,32,64` it should be the same, however the polynomial is incorrect. What is the problem?

Comment: The problem that I see, is that it is not very accurate. Even if I tried 1,4,9,25... It does not pass through all of the points as it should. Both of these are perfect polynomials that can be expressed as an equation however, the computer is not getting the equation correct. How do I change that?

Comment: It works for `1,4,9,16,25,36` but not `1,2,4,8,16` is there a reason why? And how do I find  which degree works best?

Comment: Why do you think it isn't accurate? It is the best you can get given a second degree equation.  `f(0)=1,f(1)=4,f(2)=9,f(3)=25` can't be a perfect 2nd degree polynomial.  With `n` points, you always can make a `n-1` degree equation, but it can easily be jumping up and down between the given points.  Often polynomials aren't the best choice to approximate some given points.  This is a quite complicated topic, you might have a look at [scipy's tutorial about smoothing splines](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/interpolate/smoothing_splines.html)

Comment: The higher degree polynomial works really well, but I have one last question. How do I make it so that only the two polynomials that fit well show, since if I want to have really large data sets, there will be too many polynomials?

Comment: Maybe using `for degree in range(max(0, len(x)-2), len(x)):`? It depends on what you want, and how your data look like.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [1, 2, 4, 8]

coeffs = np.polyfit(x, y, 2)
print(coeffs)
poly = np.poly1d(coeffs)
print(poly)

x_cont = np.linspace(0, 4, 81)
y_cont = poly(x_cont)

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(x_cont, y_cont)
plt.grid(1)
plt.show()
```

Executing the code, you have the graph above and this is printed in the terminal:

```
[ 0.75 -1.45  1.75]
      2
0.75 x - 1.45 x + 1.75
```

It seems to me that you had false expectations about the output of `polyfit`.